# Can't run a js from php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a website with my own controller. I'm almost done but there is a little problem. I get css, extra js(jquery) and html files from DB but js(jquery) doesn't seem to work. I echo it to my code but can't get anything done. I'm including Jquery files before this code so I don't get any error.

```
<?php echo '<script type="text/javascript"> ' . $js . '</script>';?>
```

This is the code I'm trying. If you want to check the site you can see

http://www.devplus.co/english/about-us

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly isn't working on your site?

Comment: Also - why do you include `jquery-migrate`?

Comment: I'm trying to make a animated progress bar work. The code is like this:      $(function() {
   $(".meter > span").each(function() {
    $(this)
     .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
     .width(0)
     .animate({
      width: $(this).data("origWidth")
     }, 1200);
   });
  });

Comment: I have no clue why jquery doesn't work.

Comment: Please include all relevant code in the body of the question. A link to your website will be useless to future visitors after you've fixed it. You should also look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for tips on building example code that narrows down the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also targetting a `span` while the only child element of your `.meters` div are `strong` elements. Here is a working code for me on your site :

```
    $().ready(function() {
        $(".meter > strong").each(function() {
            $(this)
                .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
                .width(0)
                .animate({
                    width: $(this).data("origWidth")
                }, 1200);
        });
    });
```

Comment: I've changed js to   $(function() {
   $(".meter > strong").each(function() {
    $(this)
     .data("origWidth", $(this).width())
     .width(0)
     .animate({
      width: $(this).data("origWidth")
     }, 1200);
   });
  });    But not working

Comment: You now have to call the function you wrote by adding **()** : 
`$(function() {... your code here ...})();`

Comment: I tried it just like you did ant now I get js error. Can you check it please?

Comment: I juste edited my answer. I replaced your `$(function())()` by a `$().ready();` and it's now working for me when I launch it in the console on your website.